# How to do a scatter plot in matplotlib with the color of the marker based on a third value?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've got three lists `x`, `y`, and `z` and what I want to do is have a scatter plot using `x` and `y` but have the color of the point be based on `z` (e.g. going from green to red as `z` goes from `0` to `1`). Is this possible?

Comment: Sure. Have you tried using `cmap` yet?

Comment: I have now! Thanks @BigBen, that's perfect.

Comment: You may want to look into using seaborn. Here is an example: https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/scatterplot_sizes.html